# In 2.8, Blender crashes while rendering trees

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to render a scene and in both render engines it crashes right before it would start making the image. I thought trees were the issue so i tested the render without them, but it crashed anyways. It might be my computer not being the best too, but if anyone knows a fix please tell me what's wrong.
Computer Specs: AMD Fx4300 (3.8GHz), 16GB RAM, AMD Radeon 260x (2GB), windows 10)
[image: screencap is rendering with eevee]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay I fixed it, not by finding out what was wrong, but just by re-making the model. Same blender file, I just deleted the model and re-made them and now it's not giving me the problem.

Answer (score 2):

i think 6 subdivisions are way to high. reduce to 2 and test it again..
you can open Task Manager if you are on Windows and check the MemoryManagement. then see if it fills your Memory.

you can also start blender with debugging turned on then you get a report when blender crash and close and you have some more Information.

Start blender_debog_log.cmd and wait for the crash

[image]

Comment: I lowered the subdivisions and tried it again while watching my memory this time, and my memory seems to be the issue as it crashed once it got too high. I think the amount of pines on the trees is just too much to handle for my computer, so I'll tweak the amount. thanks for helping!

Comment: your welcome, glad to help out. 
one more Question - do you duplicated the trees with Ctrl-D or did you made  linked duplicates with Alt-D. i have read somewhere that linked duplicates use less Memory.

Comment: Good to know as I was just using Ctrl+D but even without the trees the render would crash. I ran it through the debug and got an "Unrecognized Exception" error. Not really sure what this means, but I might just try re-creating this project and seeing if I run into the same issues.