# blender automatically closes while rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, render-passes

I have to render a single frame and it's almost done every time for up to  80 percent and closes all of a sudden and that's totally screwing me up I set frame size to 1920*1920 and 100 percent render quality can someone tell me what's the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps

[In 2.8, Blender crashes while rendering trees](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153013/in-2-8-blender-crashes-while-rendering-trees/153064#153064)

Start Blender with debug options to log what is Happening

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you run out of RAM. Then, your OS closes it. Try lowering the number of threads - it'll render slower, but fully.
Change the threads mode to fixed, then set a number of threads to something lower than the auto one.
[image: Render settings example]

Comment: first thanks for the reply man ,can you please send me the screen shot for optimal solution for render setting