# Blender 2.8 crashes when pressing F12

Tags: rendering, error

So the problem I have is that whenever I render something in blender, the entire program closes. Even when rendering the default scene (a cube, a light, and a camera). I am not sure why. I'm using blender 2.8 with Windows 7 on a Dell Latitude E630 with core i5 and 8gb ram, integrated graphics. When I press F12, a new window opens but then both the new window and blender immediately close.

Update:
I tried debug mode and this is the message I got:
Switching to fully guarded memory allocator.
Blender 2.80 (sub 75)
Build: 2019-07-29 09:44 AM Windows 
argv[0] = blender
argv[1] = --debug
argv[2] = --python-expr
argv[3] = import bpy; bpy.ops.wm.sysinfo(filepath=r'C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Temp\blender\debug_logs\blender_system_info.txt')
Read prefs: C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\config\userpref.blend
read file 
  Version 280 sub 39 date unknown hash unknown
found bundled python: C:\Users\Guest\Desktop\Search\Blender\2.80\python
Evaluate all animation - 1.000000
    No Actions, so no animation needs to be evaluated...
GPUShader: compile error:
===== shader string 1 ====
 1  #version 330
===== shader string 2 ====
 2  #define GPU_FRAGMENT_SHADER
===== shader string 3 ====
 3  #extension GL_ARB_texture_gather: enable
 4  #define GPU_ARB_texture_gather
 5  #extension GL_ARB_texture_query_lod: enable
===== shader string 4 ====
 6  #define GPU_NVIDIA
 7  #define OS_WIN
===== shader string 5 ====
 8  #define ESM
 9  #define COPY
===== shader string 6 ====
10  /* Copy the depth only shadowmap into another texture while converting

11   * to linear depth (or other storage method) and doing a 3x3 box filter. */

12

13  layout(std140) uniform shadow_render_block

14  {

15    /* Use vectors to avoid alignement padding. */

16    ivec4 shadowSampleCount;

17    vec4 shadowInvSampleCount;

18    vec4 filterSize;

19    int viewCount;

20    int baseId;

21    float cubeTexelSize;

22    float storedTexelSize;

23    float nearClip;

24    float farClip;

25    float exponent;

26  };

27

28  #ifdef CSM

29  uniform sampler2DArray shadowTexture;

30  #else

31  uniform samplerCube shadowTexture;

32  #endif

33

34  flat in int layerID;

35

36  #ifdef CSM

37  #  define cascadeID layerID

38  #else

39  #  define cascadeID 0

40  #endif

41

42  out vec4 FragColor;

43

44  #define linear_depth(z) \

45    ((nearClip * farClip) / (clamp(z, 0.0, 0.999999) * (nearClip - farClip) + farClip))

46

47  /* add bias so background filtering does not bleed into shadow map */

48  #define BACKGROUND_BIAS 0.05

49

50  #ifdef CSM

51  vec4 get_world_distance(vec4 depths, vec3 cos[4])

52  {

53    depths += step(vec4(0.9999), depths) * BACKGROUND_BIAS;

54    return clamp(

55        depths * abs(farClip - nearClip), 0.0, 1e10); /* Same factor as in shadow_cascade(). */

56  }

57

58  float get_world_distance(float depth, vec3 cos)

59  {

60    depth += step(0.9999, depth) * BACKGROUND_BIAS;

61    return clamp(

62        depth * abs(farClip - nearClip), 0.0, 1e10); /* Same factor as in shadow_cascade(). */

63  }

64

65  #else /* CUBEMAP */

66  vec4 get_world_distance(vec4 depths, vec3 cos[4])

67  {

68    depths = linear_depth(depths);

69    cos[0] = normalize(abs(cos[0]));

70    cos[1] = normalize(abs(cos[1]));

71    cos[2] = normalize(abs(cos[2]));

72    cos[3] = normalize(abs(cos[3]));

73    vec4 cos_vec;

74    cos_vec.x = max(cos[0].x, max(cos[0].y, cos[0].z));

75    cos_vec.y = max(cos[1].x, max(cos[1].y, cos[1].z));

76    cos_vec.z = max(cos[2].x, max(cos[2].y, cos[2].z));

77    cos_vec.w = max(cos[3].x, max(cos[3].y, cos[3].z));

78    return depths / cos_vec;

79  }

80

81  float get_world_distance(float depth, vec3 cos)

82  {

83    depth = linear_depth(depth);

84    cos = normalize(abs(cos));

85    float cos_vec = max(cos.x, max(cos.y, cos.z));

86    return depth / cos_vec;

87  }

88  #endif

89

90  /* Marco Salvi's GDC 2008 presentation about shadow maps pre-filtering techniques slide 24 */

91  #define ln_space_prefilter_step(ref, sample) exp(sample - ref)

92  #define ln_space_prefilter_finalize(ref, sum) (ref + log(SAMPLE_WEIGHT * sum))

93

94  #define SAMPLE_WEIGHT 0.11111

95

96  #ifdef ESM

97  void prefilter(vec4 depths, float ref, inout float accum)

98  {

99    accum += dot(ln_space_prefilter_step(ref, depths), vec4(1.0));

100  }

101  #else /* VSM */

102  void prefilter(vec4 depths, float ref, inout vec2 accum)

103  {

104    vec4 depths_sqr = depths * depths;

105    accum += vec2(dot(vec4(1.0), depths), dot(vec4(1.0), depths_sqr)) * SAMPLE_WEIGHT;

106  }

107  #endif

108

109  #ifdef CSM

110  vec3 get_texco(vec2 uvs, vec2 ofs)

111  {

112    return vec3(uvs + ofs, float(cascadeID));

113  }

114  #else /* CUBEMAP */

115  const vec3 minorAxisX[6] = vec3[6](vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f),

116                                     vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),

117                                     vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),

118                                     vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),

119                                     vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),

120                                     vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

121

122  const vec3 minorAxisY[6] = vec3[6](vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f),

123                                     vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f),

124                                     vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),

125                                     vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f),

126                                     vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f),

127                                     vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));

128

129  const vec3 majorAxis[6] = vec3[6](vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),

130                                    vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),

131                                    vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),

132                                    vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f),

133                                    vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),

134                                    vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));

135

136  vec3 get_texco(vec2 uvs, vec2 ofs)

137  {

138    uvs += ofs;

139    return majorAxis[layerID] + uvs.x * minorAxisX[layerID] + uvs.y * minorAxisY[layerID];

140  }

141  #endif

142

143  void main()

144  {

145    /* Copy the depth only shadowmap into another texture while converting

146     * to linear depth and do a 3x3 box blur. */

147

148  #ifdef CSM

149    vec2 uvs = gl_FragCoord.xy * storedTexelSize;

150  #else /* CUBEMAP */

151    vec2 uvs = gl_FragCoord.xy * cubeTexelSize * 2.0 - 1.0;

152  #endif

153

154    /* Center texel */

155    vec3 co = get_texco(uvs, vec2(0.0));

156    float depth = texture(shadowTexture, co).r;

157    depth = get_world_distance(depth, co);

158

159    if (filterSize[cascadeID] == 0.0) {

160  #ifdef ESM

161      FragColor = vec4(depth);

162  #else /* VSM */

163      FragColor = vec2(depth, depth * depth).xyxy;

164  #endif

165      return;

166    }

167

168  #ifdef ESM

169    float ref = depth;

170    float accum = 1.0;

171  #else /* VSM */

172    float ref = 0.0; /* UNUSED */

173    vec2 accum = vec2(depth, depth * depth) * SAMPLE_WEIGHT;

174  #endif

175

176    vec3 ofs = vec3(1.0, 0.0, -1.0) * filterSize[cascadeID];

177

178    vec3 cos[4];

179    cos[0] = get_texco(uvs, ofs.zz);

180    cos[1] = get_texco(uvs, ofs.yz);

181    cos[2] = get_texco(uvs, ofs.xz);

182    cos[3] = get_texco(uvs, ofs.zy);

183

184    vec4 depths;

185    depths.x = texture(shadowTexture, cos[0]).r;

186    depths.y = texture(shadowTexture, cos[1]).r;

187    depths.z = texture(shadowTexture, cos[2]).r;

188    depths.w = texture(shadowTexture, cos[3]).r;

189    depths = get_world_distance(depths, cos);

190    prefilter(depths, ref, accum);

191

192    cos[0] = get_texco(uvs, ofs.xy);

193    cos[1] = get_texco(uvs, ofs.zx);

194    cos[2] = get_texco(uvs, ofs.yx);

195    cos[3] = get_texco(uvs, ofs.xx);

196    depths.x = texture(shadowTexture, cos[0]).r;

197    depths.y = texture(shadowTexture, cos[1]).r;

198    depths.z = texture(shadowTexture, cos[2]).r;

199    depths.w = texture(shadowTexture, cos[3]).r;

200    depths = get_world_distance(depths, cos);

201    prefilter(depths, ref, accum);

202

203  #ifdef ESM

204    accum = ln_space_prefilter_finalize(ref, accum);

205  #endif

206    /* Clamp infinite sum. */

207    FragColor = vec2(clamp(accum, 0.0, 1e16)).xyxy;

208  }

0(207) : error C7011: implicit cast from "float" to "vec4"

GPUShader: compile error:
===== shader string 1 ====
 1  #version 330
===== shader string 2 ====
 2  #define GPU_FRAGMENT_SHADER
===== shader string 3 ====
 3  #extension GL_ARB_texture_gather: enable
 4  #define GPU_ARB_texture_gather
 5  #extension GL_ARB_texture_query_lod: enable
===== shader string 4 ====
 6  #define GPU_NVIDIA
 7  #define OS_WIN
===== shader string 5 ====
 8  #define ESM
 9  #define COPY
10  #define CSM
===== shader string 6 ====
11  /* Copy the depth only shadowmap into another texture while converting

12   * to linear depth (or other storage method) and doing a 3x3 box filter. */

13

14  layout(std140) uniform shadow_render_block

15  {

16    /* Use vectors to avoid alignement padding. */

17    ivec4 shadowSampleCount;

18    vec4 shadowInvSampleCount;

19    vec4 filterSize;

20    int viewCount;

21    int baseId;

22    float cubeTexelSize;

23    float storedTexelSize;

24    float nearClip;

25    float farClip;

26    float exponent;

27  };

28

29  #ifdef CSM

30  uniform sampler2DArray shadowTexture;

31  #else

32  uniform samplerCube shadowTexture;

33  #endif

34

35  flat in int layerID;

36

37  #ifdef CSM

38  #  define cascadeID layerID

39  #else

40  #  define cascadeID 0

41  #endif

42

43  out vec4 FragColor;

44

45  #define linear_depth(z) \

46    ((nearClip * farClip) / (clamp(z, 0.0, 0.999999) * (nearClip - farClip) + farClip))

47

48  /* add bias so background filtering does not bleed into shadow map */

49  #define BACKGROUND_BIAS 0.05

50

51  #ifdef CSM

52  vec4 get_world_distance(vec4 depths, vec3 cos[4])

53  {

54    depths += step(vec4(0.9999), depths) * BACKGROUND_BIAS;

55    return clamp(

56        depths * abs(farClip - nearClip), 0.0, 1e10); /* Same factor as in shadow_cascade(). */

57  }

58

59  float get_world_distance(float depth, vec3 cos)

60  {

61    depth += step(0.9999, depth) * BACKGROUND_BIAS;

62    return clamp(

63        depth * abs(farClip - nearClip), 0.0, 1e10); /* Same factor as in shadow_cascade(). */

64  }

65

66  #else /* CUBEMAP */

67  vec4 get_world_distance(vec4 depths, vec3 cos[4])

68  {

69    depths = linear_depth(depths);

70    cos[0] = normalize(abs(cos[0]));

71    cos[1] = normalize(abs(cos[1]));

72    cos[2] = normalize(abs(cos[2]));

73    cos[3] = normalize(abs(cos[3]));

74    vec4 cos_vec;

75    cos_vec.x = max(cos[0].x, max(cos[0].y, cos[0].z));

76    cos_vec.y = max(cos[1].x, max(cos[1].y, cos[1].z));

77    cos_vec.z = max(cos[2].x, max(cos[2].y, cos[2].z));

78    cos_vec.w = max(cos[3].x, max(cos[3].y, cos[3].z));

79    return depths / cos_vec;

80  }

81

82  float get_world_distance(float depth, vec3 cos)

83  {

84    depth = linear_depth(depth);

85    cos = normalize(abs(cos));

86    float cos_vec = max(cos.x, max(cos.y, cos.z));

87    return depth / cos_vec;

88  }

89  #endif

90

91  /* Marco Salvi's GDC 2008 presentation about shadow maps pre-filtering techniques slide 24 */

92  #define ln_space_prefilter_step(ref, sample) exp(sample - ref)

93  #define ln_space_prefilter_finalize(ref, sum) (ref + log(SAMPLE_WEIGHT * sum))

94

95  #define SAMPLE_WEIGHT 0.11111

96

97  #ifdef ESM

98  void prefilter(vec4 depths, float ref, inout float accum)

99  {

100    accum += dot(ln_space_prefilter_step(ref, depths), vec4(1.0));

101  }

102  #else /* VSM */

103  void prefilter(vec4 depths, float ref, inout vec2 accum)

104  {

105    vec4 depths_sqr = depths * depths;

106    accum += vec2(dot(vec4(1.0), depths), dot(vec4(1.0), depths_sqr)) * SAMPLE_WEIGHT;

107  }

108  #endif

109

110  #ifdef CSM

111  vec3 get_texco(vec2 uvs, vec2 ofs)

112  {

113    return vec3(uvs + ofs, float(cascadeID));

114  }

115  #else /* CUBEMAP */

116  const vec3 minorAxisX[6] = vec3[6](vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f),

117                                     vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),

118                                     vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),

119                                     vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),

120                                     vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),

121                                     vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

122

123  const vec3 minorAxisY[6] = vec3[6](vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f),

124                                     vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f),

125                                     vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),

126                                     vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f),

127                                     vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f),

128                                     vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));

129

130  const vec3 majorAxis[6] = vec3[6](vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),

131                                    vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),

132                                    vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),

133                                    vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f),

134                                    vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),

135                                    vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));

136

137  vec3 get_texco(vec2 uvs, vec2 ofs)

138  {

139    uvs += ofs;

140    return majorAxis[layerID] + uvs.x * minorAxisX[layerID] + uvs.y * minorAxisY[layerID];

141  }

142  #endif

143

144  void main()

145  {

146    /* Copy the depth only shadowmap into another texture while converting

147     * to linear depth and do a 3x3 box blur. */

148

149  #ifdef CSM

150    vec2 uvs = gl_FragCoord.xy * storedTexelSize;

151  #else /* CUBEMAP */

152    vec2 uvs = gl_FragCoord.xy * cubeTexelSize * 2.0 - 1.0;

153  #endif

154

155    /* Center texel */

156    vec3 co = get_texco(uvs, vec2(0.0));

157    float depth = texture(shadowTexture, co).r;

158    depth = get_world_distance(depth, co);

159

160    if (filterSize[cascadeID] == 0.0) {

161  #ifdef ESM

162      FragColor = vec4(depth);

163  #else /* VSM */

164      FragColor = vec2(depth, depth * depth).xyxy;

165  #endif

166      return;

167    }

168

169  #ifdef ESM

170    float ref = depth;

171    float accum = 1.0;

172  #else /* VSM */

173    float ref = 0.0; /* UNUSED */

174    vec2 accum = vec2(depth, depth * depth) * SAMPLE_WEIGHT;

175  #endif

176

177    vec3 ofs = vec3(1.0, 0.0, -1.0) * filterSize[cascadeID];

178

179    vec3 cos[4];

180    cos[0] = get_texco(uvs, ofs.zz);

181    cos[1] = get_texco(uvs, ofs.yz);

182    cos[2] = get_texco(uvs, ofs.xz);

183    cos[3] = get_texco(uvs, ofs.zy);

184

185    vec4 depths;

186    depths.x = texture(shadowTexture, cos[0]).r;

187    depths.y = texture(shadowTexture, cos[1]).r;

188    depths.z = texture(shadowTexture, cos[2]).r;

189    depths.w = texture(shadowTexture, cos[3]).r;

190    depths = get_world_distance(depths, cos);

191    prefilter(depths, ref, accum);

192

193    cos[0] = get_texco(uvs, ofs.xy);

194    cos[1] = get_texco(uvs, ofs.zx);

195    cos[2] = get_texco(uvs, ofs.yx);

196    cos[3] = get_texco(uvs, ofs.xx);

197    depths.x = texture(shadowTexture, cos[0]).r;

198    depths.y = texture(shadowTexture, cos[1]).r;

199    depths.z = texture(shadowTexture, cos[2]).r;

200    depths.w = texture(shadowTexture, cos[3]).r;

201    depths = get_world_distance(depths, cos);

202    prefilter(depths, ref, accum);

203

204  #ifdef ESM

205    accum = ln_space_prefilter_finalize(ref, accum);

206  #endif

207    /* Clamp infinite sum. */

208    FragColor = vec2(clamp(accum, 0.0, 1e16)).xyxy;

209  }

0(208) : error C7011: implicit cast from "float" to "vec4"

Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x0000000140D4B354
Module  : C:\Users\Guest\Desktop\Search\Blender\blender.exe

Comment: you can eventually pin down your problem, when you start Blender in Debug-Mode as stated here:  
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153013/in-2-8-blender-crashes-while-rendering-trees/153064#153064
8 GByte Ram seems a bit low, or maybe your graphics card cant handle GPU Rendering so you have to switch to CPU Rendering in pref's. please provide more Information and eventually try a different build https://download.blender.org/release/

Comment: Rendering in Blender worked fine in 2.79, so 8gb should be enough unless Blender system requirements changed... I'll try debug mode, hopefully fixes the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately 2.80 requires more ram than 2.79, changes have been made that use more ram to get better performance, but I would expect the default scene to render in 8G. Have you started with factory settings when rendering the default scene? Using cycles and evee?