# Blender console on quiting

Tags: interface

Quite simple question really, I am using Blender 2.80 on Windows 10, Intel + Nvidia based system. Blender runs really well, no problems, however, when I have finished with Blender and close the app there is a console (command) window that briefly flashes up. It is too quick to read the messages, but I do see "error" in the list of messages. I would like to somehow keep this console open on Blender quit so I can read the messages and fix any issues.
Or is it possible to get Blender to log the messages to a file for later reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start Blender in Debug-Mode as stated here:

[In 2.8, Blender crashes while rendering trees](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153013/in-2-8-blender-crashes-while-rendering-trees/153064#153064)

that creates a log file which you can inspect